# fancybox that displays MVC Model string property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, string, properties, fancybox

I would like to display an MVC model property of type string in a jQuery fancybox.  I've done it with a simple js alert using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if ('<%=Model.PopupMessage%>' != "") {
    alert('<%=Model.PopupMessage%>');
}
</script>
```

I don't see any examples of this on fancybox.net or anywhere on the internet for that matter.  Any thoughts?

Comment: have you tried `$.fancybox('<%=Model.PopupMessage%>')`? ... instead of the `alert()`

Comment: Yes, and no success.  I've tried enclosing <%=Model.PopupMessage%> in single and double quotes.

Comment: do you get the `alert()`? if so maybe you can try `$.fancybox({content: '<%=Model.PopupMessage%>'})` instead.